# ASP.NET Regex - Validate what's after the 3rd character

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I need to validate if the remaining characters after the 3rd character are numeric. The string after the 3rd character is 7 characters long.

I have the regex for the last remaining to be numeric

Regex:

`([0-9]{7})`

I need to add the other chunk that starts the validation at the 4th character.

An example of text to be validated would be something like this "PRA0987654".
The 1st 3 characters are always alphabetic and they're either never the same. Another example could be "ACR0986745" So I can't just do:

`R([0-9]{7})`

or

`A([0-9]{7})`

Cause the 3rd character is never the same.

An incorrect validation would be something like this "ZZQA098345". It's incorrect cause the 4th character is alphabetic and not numeric.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you don't need to check for unique letters this is 3 chars, 7 digits: `^[A-Z]{3}\d{7}$`

Comment: Please be more clear about "they're either never the same". Can the same character appear more than once in the first the characters? I.e. does `[A-Z]{3}` validate the first three characters or not? Please also describe what you've tried so far, what that did, and how that's different from what you wanted to happen. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @AlexK.: IMHO you should undelete your previous answer. While I _think_ that there's a requirement that the first three characters each are different from each other, it's not clear at all from the question and I could easily be mistaken. You might as well answer the plausible alternative and see what happens. :)

Comment: Sorry my english is kinda bad, but yes you can have the 1st 3 be repeated letters like "AAA0456754"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try your regex with this excelent tool: http://rubular.com/

For your question, I think it could be

```
(.{3}\d{7}$)
```